# How to delay transition until previous one has completed. (ng-show)

Tags: css, angularjs, css-animations, ng-animate

I have a series of div tags that contain information about an specific section. There can only be one div block visible at a time, and in order to accomplish this I have an ng-show statement that bases the condition on a currently set name. My markup looks similar to this.

```css
.infoBlock {
  transition: all .2s linear;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.infoBlock.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="infoBlock" ng-show="selectedCategory == 'name1'">
  <p>
    ...some text
  </p>

</div>


<div class="infoBlock" ng-show="selectedCategory == 'name2'">
  <p>
    ...some text
  </p>

</div>
```

The problem is that since the div's take the place of the previously shown one, a div that is about to be shown appears before the current one has a chance to disappear.

I have tried to set a `transition-delay` on the `.infoBlock` class but that did not solve the problem, and I cannot use `setTimeout()` whenever I set `selectedCategory` because it would have no effect since the same variable controls the appearance of both blocks.

Comment: What do you have so far? When is the animation happening? Can you add the relevant part of the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play a trick with `ng-hide-animate` and `ng-hide-remove-active` classes:

```css
    .infoBlock.ng-hide-remove-active {
       transition-delay: 0.4s;
    }
    .infoBlock.ng-hide-animate {
       position:absolute;
    }
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/w0SIch3yIHuWldyonMLF

Comment: Is it possible to add transition-delay here when the model value is changing? `<div>{{mainCtrl.errorMsg}}</div>`